# Event versus Form

Tags: civimember

If you want to create a form for someone to sign up as a contact or for someone to make a donation, do you create an event?  Or, are there forms somewhere to use?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to SE! You certainly don't want to create an event for either of those scenarios. You just need to look at a bit more documentation (daunting at first but well worth looking through it all to see all the capabilities of CiviCRM).

For creating signing up as contact - the use profiles (see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/)

For the donation you should create an online contribution (see https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/online-contributions/)